# insertar datos en dos servidores simultaneamente

Tags: sql-server

Tengo mi servidor vinculado a otro servidor, lo que necesito es un procedimiento almacenado donde al momento de insertar datos en una tabla de mi servidor al mismo tiempo inserte en otra tabla de mi servidor vinculado

Comment: Y si tratas de acceder a tu otro servidor desde el sp de tu servidor asi: **INSERT INTO  [NombreDeLaIntanciaSQLDelOtroServidor].[NombreBaseDatos].[NombreDelSchema].[NombreDeLaTabla](campo) VALUES('dato')**

Comment: Podrías [edit] tu pregunta he incluir más detalles a tu pregunta. ¿Que tablas, columnas, nombre del servidor?.

Comment: Muchas gracias andrezi me ayudó mucho ✌

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumiendo que tiene su servidor vinculado funcionando, use esto:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertDataLinkedServer
as
INSERT INTO TestTable (COLUMN_NAME) values ('123') -- LOCAL
INSERT INTO [TargetServer].[Database].[dbo].TestTable (COLUMN_NAME) values ('123') -- VINCULADO (LINKED SERVER)
```

**TargetServer** = nombre de su servidor vinculado